# Lightning Action Override not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, button-overrides

I saw https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_action_overrides.htm in the release notes and and to use it, but I can't get it to work.

I am wondering if this is working?
How do I use it?

I tried the example on the release notes with a detail edit button/action as well as the list view new button for a custom object, but was not able to get it to work.  I tried several other combinations of interfaces besides the three they mention, but nothing worked.

The behavior is that the button is overridden, but I don't think the component every is executed.  Even javascript in the doInit event function does not fire.

I am wondering if anyone got it working.

Ideally I would like to override the new button on the list view with this component.

I pretty much followed the release example but added access="global" and tried several other interfaces, but nothing made the component render or the javascript in the init function execute.

thanks to all in advanced!

Comment: Some patch came in recently and resolved this

Comment: FYI - I feel its not off topic to share this info, even if it's a release bug.  PM's scan this and offer much better support than the typical support avenues.  Sometime's it's the quickest way to communicate what is not working.  If you have a better avenue please share